# Why OpenSL ES won't play audio every time an application is started

Tags: android, c++, audio, opensl

I'm implementing audio playback into my game engine using OpenSL ES on Android. So far I'm supporting Android file descriptor data locators (AndroidFD) only. The problem is, that the audio playback won't always work if I'm using wrapper classes for OpenSL ES.

The wrappers:

AudioEngine.cpp

```
AudioEngine::AudioEngine()
    : _engine(NULL),
      _engineInterface(NULL),
      _outputMix(NULL)
{
    createEngine();
    createOutputMix();
}

AudioEngine::~AudioEngine()
{
    (*_outputMix)->Destroy(_outputMix);
    (*_engine)->Destroy(_engine);
}

Sound* AudioEngine::loadSound(const String& filename) const
{
    return NEW Sound(_engineInterface, _outputMix, filename);
}


// Private

void AudioEngine::createEngine()
{
    Uint32 result = slCreateEngine(&_engine, 0u, NULL, 0u, NULL, NULL);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::AudioEngine (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to create the engine");

    result = (*_engine)->Realize(_engine, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::AudioEngine (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to initialise the engine");

    result = (*_engine)->GetInterface(_engine, SL_IID_ENGINE, &_engineInterface);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::AudioEngine (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to get the engine interface");
}

void AudioEngine::createOutputMix()
{
    Uint32 result = (*_engineInterface)->CreateOutputMix(_engineInterface, &_outputMix, 0u,
        NULL, NULL);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::AudioEngine (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to create the output mix");

    result = (*_outputMix)->Realize(_outputMix, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::AudioEngine (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to initialise the output mix");
}
```

Sound.cpp

```
// Public

Sound::Sound(SLEngineItf engineInterface, SLObjectItf outputMix, const String& filename)
    : _engineInterface(engineInterface),
      _outputMix(outputMix),
      _player(NULL),
      _playerInterface(NULL)
{
    // Member (SLDataFormat_MIME)
    _dataSourceFormat.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME;
    _dataSourceFormat.mimeType = NULL;
    _dataSourceFormat.containerType = SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED;

    // Member (SLDataLocator_AndroidFD)
    _dataSourceLocator.locatorType = SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDFD;

    AAssetManager* assetManager = Application::assetManager();
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, filename.data(), AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

    _dataSourceLocator.fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset,
        reinterpret_cast<off_t*>(&_dataSourceLocator.offset),
        reinterpret_cast<off_t*>(&_dataSourceLocator.length));

    AAsset_close(asset);
    createPlayer();
}

Sound::~Sound()
{
    (*_player)->Destroy(_player);
}

void Sound::play() const
{
    const Uint32 result = (*_playerInterface)->SetPlayState(_playerInterface,
        SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::Sound (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to set the play state"); 
}


// Private

void Sound::createPlayer()
{
    SLDataSource dataSource =
    {
        &_dataSourceLocator,
        &_dataSourceFormat
    };

    SLDataLocator_OutputMix outputMixLocator =
    {
        SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX,
        _outputMix
    };

    SLDataSink dataSink =
    {
        &outputMixLocator,
        NULL
    };

    Uint32 result = (*_engineInterface)->CreateAudioPlayer(_engineInterface, &_player,
        &dataSource, &dataSink, 0u, NULL, NULL);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::Sound (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to create a player");

    result = (*_player)->Realize(_player, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::Sound (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to initialise the player");

    result = (*_player)->GetInterface(_player, SL_IID_PLAY, &_playerInterface);

    CHECK_OPENSLES_ERROR(result, "Platform::SoundInstance (OpenSLES)",
        "Failed to get the player interface");
}
```

Game.cpp

```
Game::initialise()
{
    _audioEngine = NEW AudioEngine();
    _sound = _audioEngine->loadSound("music.ogg");
    _sound->play();
}
```

When the application starts, the sound won't always play. If I write all OpenSL ES code above inside Game::initialise(), the sound will always play. I can't figure out why the same code won't work inside the wrapper classes.

I ran the application on Samsung Galaxy S III (GT-I9305), Android 4.2.2, CyanogenMod 10.1.3-i9305

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to keep dataSource, outputMixLocator and dataSink in scope while the sound is being played, since they are passed as pointers. Make them member variables to keep them alive for the lifetime of the object.